# Convert ISO-8601 timestamp from UTC-7:00 to "Europe/Amsterdam" (CEST) time, which is UTC+2:00

Tags: perl, datetime-format, iso8601

In Perl I use a bash command to convert an ISO-8601 timestamp to local format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`.

These timestamps, for example, are used in Google Cloud JSON APIs. For example
`2016-08-09T17:05:05.414-07:00`. Check the source below for a working example.

This works fine, but is there a way to accomplish the same in Perl without using a bash command? Of course I'm sure there is, but I couldn't find anything simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $f = `date -d 2016-08-09T17:05:05.414-07:00 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`;
chop $f;

print "$f\n";    # 2016-08-10 02:05:05
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) modules are the obvious choice for this. Your original string is formatted according to the ISO-8601 standard so the [`DateTime::Format::ISO8601`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601) will parse it directly

Then it is simply a matter of setting the time zone to zero and formatting the result as required

Here's the code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

say localise_time('2016-08-09T17:05:05.414-07:00');

sub localise_time {
    my ($dt) = @_;

    $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($dt);
    $dt->set_time_zone('Europe/Amsterdam');

    $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}
```

#### output

```
2016-08-10 02:05:05
```

Comment: "I'm not sure about your arithmetic! 17:05:05 on 9 August plus seven hours for the time zone is 00:05:05 on 10 August"

Comment: The +2 hours is because of my timezone CEST/Amsterdam

Comment: Ah! Then you will want `$dt->set_time_zone('2:00')`. For some reason `$dt->set_time_zone('CEST/Amsterdam')` doesn't work, but I'm looking at why.
`

Comment: in your solution, can you use the extra calculation from UTC to CEST, thus adding the extra 2 hours?

Comment: @Eric: I've used `Europe/Amsterdam` instead, which works fine. See my amended answer.

Comment: @Eric: Please fix your question to say that you want to move from UTC-7:00 (California?) to "Europe/Amsterdam" (CEST) time, which is UTC+2:00.

Comment: @Eric: You will probably find that you can use `$dt->set_time_zone('local')` but that is platform-dependent.

Comment: tested successfully your solution and fixed the question